# Loader and LoaderManager - how to determine if there was an error loading

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I think I understand how loaders are supposed to work, etc, but I'm not quite sure how a Loader would signal to the LoaderManager, or to the application, that it did not complete successfully.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way. Catch all exceptions, and return some class that has an optional `Exception error` field. Check if the exception is null to see if the call succeeded. Something like:

```
public class LoaderResult<T> {

    private T data;
    private Exception error;

    private LoaderResult(T data, Exception error) {
        this.data = data;
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```